# Slow to change resolution/start fullscreen apps on triplemonitor setup in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

For some reason when I start a full screen application (like a game), or change resolutions, it takes 10-30 seconds for anything to happen. This also happens when the screensaver activates or deactivates.

Basically it looks something like this:

- Start application
- Screens go blank, audio stops
- At this point everything seems frozen
- Left screen wakes up
- Middle screen wakes up
- Right screen wakes up
- Things un-freeze, audio continues

This whole sequence tends to take quite a while at worst, and it's pretty annoying to wait, especially if you're running a game and for example want to alt-tab between it and some other app you're running. It can also happen multiple times per app-launch (eg. if it's a game which runs at a different resolution)

This only begins to happen after Windows has been running for a while. It works beautifully for a while after rebooting, but then it becomes like this.

If anyone has any ideas on what could be the cause of this, or any ideas for a solution, I'd be happy to hear them. This is quite frustrating at times.

Specs:

- Windows 7 x64 Ultimate
- Intel Core i7 920 clocked at 4 GHz
- 12 GB RAM
- ATI Radeon HD 5870
- Three monitors, with resolutions as: 1920x1080, 1920x1200, 1920x1080, all connected to the Radeon, 2 via DVI (into separate DVI ports), 1 via DisplayPort

Comment: How is your third monitor attached? Is it attached to onboard gfx card or via a splitter?

Comment: Have you updated to the most recent version of catalyst? http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Comment: I have two monitors attached via DVI, the third is attached via DisplayPort - all to the Radeon (it has four outputs and supports this). Yes, I have the latest drivers and I've had this issue with earlier ones too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest ATI display driver has fixed this for me. I had tried other drivers in the past but none had helped until now... ATI drivers have generally just made things worse for things like this, but looks like there's still hope :D